# starting game again in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a flappy bird game for school and now i want to make that if jou hit te obstacle the game starts again the hit the object is no problem but the code for start the code againt is the problem do anyone know a cade for it i have already an infinity loop so anathor loop wil make the game crah i guess so i hope anyone can help me.

my code if hit helps:

```
import random
import time
import pygame
i = 1
jump = 55
xSpeler = 50
ySpeler = 100
widthSpeler = 40
heightSpeler = 40
vel = 10
vel1 = 10
# obstacle 1
xo1 = 900
yo1 = 0
ho1 = 200
wo1 = 50

xo2 = 900
yo2 = 350
ho2 = 200
wo2 = 50
# obstacle 2
xo3 = 900
yo3 = 0
ho3 = 250
wo3 = 50

xo4 = 900
yo4 = 350
ho4 = 150
wo4 = 50

def genObstacle():
    # generate and return
    # 1. pygame surface for top and bottom rects
    # 2. initial position for top rect and bottom rect
    topHeight = random.randint(10, 200)  # height for bottom obstacle
    botHeight = random.randint(10, 200)  # height for top obstacle
    top = pygame.Surface((10, topHeight)).convert()
    bot = pygame.Surface((10, botHeight)).convert()
    # return: top rect, bottom rect, top rect's position, bottom rect's position

    return [top, bot, [800, 0], [800, 500 - botHeight]]


win = pygame.display.set_mode((350, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Flappy bird")

#obstacles = [pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo1, yo1, wo1, ho1)) or pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo1, yo1, wo1, ho1)), pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo2, yo2, wo2, ho2)) or pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo2, yo2, wo2, ho2))]
#obstacles = [pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo1, yo1, wo1, ho1))]

start = time.time()
now = time.time()

pygame.init()


bi = pygame.image.load('bada.png')


yellow = pygame.image.load('yellow2.png')
yellow = pygame.transform.scale(yellow, (40, 40))

pygame.display.flip()

run = True
while run:

    win.blit(bi, (0, 0))
    pygame.time.delay(55)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    ySpeler += vel
    if ySpeler >= 500 - heightSpeler:
        ySpeler = 500 - heightSpeler

    xo1 -= vel1
    xo2 -= vel1

    if xo1 + wo1 < 0:
        xo1 = 350
    if xo2 + wo2 < 0:
        xo2 = 350

    obst1 = pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo1, yo1, wo1, ho1))
    obst2 = pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo2, yo2, wo2, ho2))

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and xSpeler > vel and ySpeler > 0:
        ySpeler -= jump

    win.blit(yellow, (xSpeler, ySpeler))

    if xo1 == xSpeler:
        

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: All you have to do is to reset all game states which have changed. You don't need to break the application loop. Just assign the initial value to all game states.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rabbid mentioned, to restart the game, reset all the game variables. You can do this in a function so it can be called during the game loop.

Try this code. Press `R` to restart the game.

```
import random
import time
import pygame

# need these variables for game play
i = jump = xSpeler = ySpeler = widthSpeler = heightSpeler = vel = vel1 = None
xo1 = yo1 = ho1 = wo1 = xo2 = yo2 = ho2 = wo2 = xo3 = yo3 = ho3 = wo3 = xo4 = yo4 = ho4 = wo4 = None

def initstate():
    # link to global variables, prevent creation of local variables
    global i, jump, xSpeler, ySpeler, widthSpeler, heightSpeler, vel, vel1
    global xo1, yo1, ho1, wo1, xo2, yo2, ho2, wo2, xo3, yo3, ho3, wo3, xo4, yo4, ho4, wo4

    i = 1
    jump = 55
    xSpeler = 50
    ySpeler = 100
    widthSpeler = 40
    heightSpeler = 40
    vel = 10
    vel1 = 10
    # obstacle 1
    xo1 = 900
    yo1 = 0
    ho1 = 200
    wo1 = 50

    xo2 = 900
    yo2 = 350
    ho2 = 200
    wo2 = 50
    # obstacle 2
    xo3 = 900
    yo3 = 0
    ho3 = 250
    wo3 = 50

    xo4 = 900
    yo4 = 350
    ho4 = 150
    wo4 = 50

initstate()  # init first time

def genObstacle():
    # generate and return
    # 1. pygame surface for top and bottom rects
    # 2. initial position for top rect and bottom rect
    topHeight = random.randint(10, 200)  # height for bottom obstacle
    botHeight = random.randint(10, 200)  # height for top obstacle
    top = pygame.Surface((10, topHeight)).convert()
    bot = pygame.Surface((10, botHeight)).convert()
    # return: top rect, bottom rect, top rect's position, bottom rect's position

    return [top, bot, [800, 0], [800, 500 - botHeight]]


win = pygame.display.set_mode((350, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Flappy bird")

#obstacles = [pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo1, yo1, wo1, ho1)) or pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo1, yo1, wo1, ho1)), pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo2, yo2, wo2, ho2)) or pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo2, yo2, wo2, ho2))]
#obstacles = [pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo1, yo1, wo1, ho1))]

start = time.time()
now = time.time()

pygame.init()


bi = pygame.image.load('cubered.png')


yellow = pygame.image.load('cubeyellow.png')
yellow = pygame.transform.scale(yellow, (40, 40))

pygame.display.flip()

run = True
while run:

    win.blit(bi, (0, 0))
    pygame.time.delay(55)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    ySpeler += vel
    if ySpeler >= 500 - heightSpeler:
        ySpeler = 500 - heightSpeler

    xo1 -= vel1
    xo2 -= vel1

    if xo1 + wo1 < 0:
        xo1 = 350
    if xo2 + wo2 < 0:
        xo2 = 350

    obst1 = pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo1, yo1, wo1, ho1))
    obst2 = pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xo2, yo2, wo2, ho2))

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and xSpeler > vel and ySpeler > 0:
        ySpeler -= jump

    if keys[pygame.K_r]:  # restart game
        win.fill((0,0,0))  # clear screen
        initstate()   # init game state
        
    win.blit(yellow, (xSpeler, ySpeler))

#    if xo1 == xSpeler:
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thanks jou Both berry much my problem is solved now and my game wil soon be don zo thanks jou